# devise rails adding user_id to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, controller, parameters

I want to add the current_user.id from devise to another model...

question model:

```
    class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :content

  validates :content, :presence => true
end
```

user model:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

my question migration:

```
class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.date :deadline
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my questions controller:

```
def create

    params[:question][:user_id]=current_user.id

    @question = Question.new(params[:question])
    if @question.save
      redirect_to questions_path, :notice => "Successfully created question."
    else
      setup_questions
      render :index
    end
  end
```

When i save the question the current_user.id won't be recorded in my database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
def create

  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  @question.user_id = current_user.id
  if @question.save
    redirect_to questions_path, :notice => "Successfully created question."
  else
    setup_questions
    render :index
  end

end
```